Vuetify3: How to disable deselection of a v-list-item?
I have a list of names that are displayed. When I click on an item, it is highlighted in blue (primary colour) and when I click on it again the highlight is removed, but the selectedUser remains the same. How do I prevent the highlight of an already selected item from being removed?

<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";

const users = ref([
      {name: "John", age: 25},
      {name: "Jane", age: 24},
      {name: "Doe", age: 26},
      {name: "Smith", age: 27},
]);

const selectedUser = ref(null);
</script>


<template>
<v-app>
   <v-card>
      <v-list>
         <v-list-item 
         v-for="user in users" :key="user.name" 
         @click="selectedUser=user"
         :value="user"
         color="primary">
            <v-list-item-title>{{user.name}}</v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>{{user.age}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
         </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
      <br><br>
      <p>
         Selected User: {{selectedUser?.name}}
      </p>
   </v-card>
</v-app>
</template>


When you click on an item, it it marked as active. When you click on it again, this status gets removed. So you have to manually maintain the status.
<script setup>
import {ref} from "vue";

const users = ref([
      {name: "John", age: 25},
      {name: "Jane", age: 24},
      {name: "Doe", age: 26},
      {name: "Smith", age: 27},
]);

const selectedUser = ref(null);
</script>


<template>
<v-app>
   <v-card>
      <v-list>
         <v-list-item 
         v-for="user in users" :key="user.name" 
         @click="selectedUser=user"
         :value="user"
         :active="user.name === selectedUser?.name"
         color="primary">
            <v-list-item-title>{{user.name}}</v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>{{user.age}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
         </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
      <br><br>
      <p>
         Selected User: {{selectedUser?.name}}
      </p>
   </v-card>
</v-app>
</template>


Use optional chaining to prevent error when selectedUser is still null, selectedUser?.name.  It also looks like you need to bind one more additional class, text-primary, with the same condition to achieve the exact styling needed

tested in Vuetify playground

This partially works - the blue colour of the v-list-item is gone, instead it remains grey (indicating that it's set to active). Thanks to your answer, I decided to look deeper into the documentation and found that there's a prop active. By binding like :active="selectedUser === user" works as expected.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-list-item/#props
